# Unable to produce visualisations to calculate topic frequency for LSI model

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, lsa

I am trying to create a graph which shows the frequency of the topics for LSI. I was able to do this for my LDA model using the same code.

When I try to visualise my LSI topics I get error messages as shown below.

The code to create the models is below:

```
# Import CSV
df_train = pd.read_csv("Fold_2.csv", engine='python',encoding='latin-1')
# Convert to list
data = df_train['Post'].values.tolist()


# Change sentences to words
def sent_to_words(sentences):
    for sentence in sentences:
        yield(gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(str(sentence), deacc=True))  # deacc=True removes punctuations
data_words = list(sent_to_words(data))

# Create bigram and trigam
bigram = gensim.models.Phrases(data_words, min_count=5, threshold=10) # higher threshold fewer phrases.
trigram = gensim.models.Phrases(bigram[data_words], threshold=10)  

bigram_mod = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigram)
trigram_mod = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(trigram)

# Define functions for stopwords, bigrams, trigrams and lemmatization
def remove_stopwords(texts):
    return [[word for word in simple_preprocess(str(doc)) if word not in stop_words] for doc in texts]

def make_bigrams(texts):
    return [bigram_mod[doc] for doc in texts]

def make_trigrams(texts):
    return [trigram_mod[bigram_mod[doc]] for doc in texts]

def lemmatization(texts, allowed_postags=['NOUN', 'ADJ', 'VERB', 'ADV']):
    """https://spacy.io/api/annotation"""
    texts_out = []
    for sent in texts:
        doc = nlp(" ".join(sent)) 
        texts_out.append([token.lemma_ for token in doc if token.pos_ in allowed_postags])
    return texts_out


# Remove Stop Words
data_words_nostops = remove_stopwords(data_words)

# Form Bigrams
data_words_bigrams = make_bigrams(data_words_nostops)

# Initialize spacy 'en' model, keeping only tagger component (for efficiency)

nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner'])

# Do lemmatization keeping only noun, adj, vb, adv
data_lemmatized = lemmatization(data_words_bigrams, allowed_postags=['NOUN'])


# Create Dictionary
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_lemmatized)

# Create Corpus
texts = data_lemmatized
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

#Create LDA model
lda_model = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus,
                                           id2word=id2word,
                                           num_topics=20, 
                                           random_state=10,
                                           update_every=1,
                                           chunksize=100,
                                           passes=5,
                                           alpha='auto',
                                           per_word_topics=True)
# Print the Keyword in the topics
doc_lda = lda_model[corpus]
x=lda_model.show_topics(num_topics=20, num_words=5,formatted=False)
topics_words = [(tp[0], [wd[0] for wd in tp[1]]) for tp in x]
print("LDA Model")

# Print The words
name = 0
words_together_list = []
for topic,words in topics_words:
        words_together= " ".join(words)
        words_together_list.append(words_together)
        name = name + 1
        print("The key word of Topic ", topic, " was: ", words_together)
# Compute Coherence Score
coherence_model_lda = CoherenceModel(model=lda_model, texts=data_lemmatized, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')
coherence_lda = coherence_model_lda.get_coherence()
print("Coherence: ", coherence_lda)

lsi_model = gensim.models.lsimodel.LsiModel(
   corpus=corpus, id2word=id2word, num_topics=20,chunksize=100
)
   
print("")
print("LSI Model")

# Print the Keywords in the topics
doc_lsi = lsi_model[corpus]

x=lsi_model.show_topics(num_topics=20, num_words=5,formatted=False)
topics_words = [(tp[0], [wd[0] for wd in tp[1]]) for tp in x]

# Print The words
name = 0
words_together_list = []
for topic,words in topics_words:
        words_together= " ".join(words)
        words_together_list.append(words_together)
        name = name + 1
        print("The key word of Topic ", topic, " was: ", words_together)
coherence_model_lsi = CoherenceModel(model=lsi_model, texts=data_lemmatized, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')
coherence_lsi = coherence_model_lsi.get_coherence()
print("Coherence: ", coherence_lsi)
```

The code for the visualisation of LSI topics is below. The same Python code worked for LSA when LSI was changed to LSI to reference the correct model.

```
#create a function to calculate topics per post
def topics_per_post(model, corpus, start=0, end=1):
    corpus_selected = corpus[start:end]
    dominant_topics = []
    topic_percentages = []
    for i, corp in enumerate(corpus_selected):
        topic_percs, wordid_topics, wordid_phivalues = model[corp]
        dominant_topic = sorted(topic_percs, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0][0]
        dominant_topics.append((i, dominant_topic))
        topic_percentages.append(topic_percs)
    return(dominant_topics, topic_percentages)       

dominant_topics, topic_percentages = topics_per_post(model=lsi_model, corpus=corpus, end=-1)            

# create bar graph of topic frequency
df = pd.DataFrame(dominant_topics, columns=['Document_Id', 'Dominant_Topic'])
dominant_topic_in_each_doc = df.groupby('Dominant_Topic').size()
df_dominant_topic_in_each_doc = dominant_topic_in_each_doc.to_frame(name='count').reset_index()

df_dominant_topic_in_each_doc['count'].plot(kind='bar', title='Topic Frequency', ylabel='Frequency',
         xlabel='Topic', figsize=(6, 5))
```

This is the error message produced:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-96b45968c3a6> in <module>()
----> 1 dominant_topics, topic_percentages = topics_per_post(model=lsi_model, corpus=corpus, end=-1)
      2 
      3 # create bar graph of topic frequency
      4 df = pd.DataFrame(dominant_topics, columns=['Document_Id', 'Dominant_Topic'])
      5 dominant_topic_in_each_doc = df.groupby('Dominant_Topic').size()

<ipython-input-26-541251ac2e71> in topics_per_post(model, corpus, start, end)
      5     topic_percentages = []
      6     for i, corp in enumerate(corpus_selected):
----> 7         topic_percs, wordid_topics, wordid_phivalues = model[corp]
      8         dominant_topic = sorted(topic_percs, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[0][0]
      9         dominant_topics.append((i, dominant_topic))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

I also tried with pyLDAvis, however, this also produced an error.

```
#Import plLDavis
import pyLDAvis
import pyLDAvis.gensim_models as gensimvis
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()

# Visualise the topics for LSI
lsi_viz = gensimvis.prepare(lsi_model, corpus, id2word)
lsi_viz
```

This produced the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-d9de743e0c86> in <module>()
      5 
      6 # Visualise the topics for LSI
----> 7 lsi_viz = gensimvis.prepare(lsi_model, corpus, id2word)
      8 lsi_viz

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyLDAvis/gensim_models.py in _extract_data(topic_model, corpus, dictionary, doc_topic_dists)
     47             gamma = topic_model.inference(corpus)
     48         else:
---> 49             gamma, _ = topic_model.inference(corpus)
     50         doc_topic_dists = gamma / gamma.sum(axis=1)[:, None]
     51     else:

AttributeError: 'LsiModel' object has no attribute 'inference'
```

I have tried some research and I cannot seem to find examples of calculating the frequency of topics across all documents for LSI using Gensim. I have also searched for these errors on stack overflow and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score -3):

Found the answer :)

```
sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()

# Get main topic in each document
for i, row in enumerate(lsi_model[corpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
        # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each document
        for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
            if j == 0:  # => dominant topic
                wp = lsi_model.show_topic(topic_num)
                topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
                sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(pd.Series([int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]), ignore_index=True)
            else:
                break
sent_topics_df.columns = ['Dominant_Topic', 'Perc_Contribution', 'Topic_Keywords']
contents = pd.Series(texts)
sent_topics_df = pd.concat([sent_topics_df, contents], axis=1)

# Format
df_dominant_topic =sent_topics_df.reset_index()
df_dominant_topic.columns = ['Document_No', 'Dominant_Topic', 'Topic_Perc_Contrib', 'Keywords', 'Text']
dominant_topic_in_each_doc = df_dominant_topic.groupby('Dominant_Topic').size()
df_dominant_topic_in_each_doc = dominant_topic_in_each_doc.to_frame(name='count').reset_index()

df_dominant_topic_in_each_doc['count'].plot(kind='bar', title='Topic Frequency', ylabel='Frequency',
         xlabel='Topic', figsize=(6, 5))
```

Comment: Please take a minute to *explain* what exactly you have changed and how the change(s) have resolved the issue, so that the thread can be possibly helpful for others in the future (which is the sole purpose of SO).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).